# Ionic Crop plugin causes build error due to type

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My Crop plugin is causing errors when I build for production.

```
$ ionic build --prod
ERROR in app/providers/photo.service.ts:22:30 - error TS2749: 'Crop' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

Here's the service:

```
import {Crop} from '@ionic-native/crop/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PhotoService {

imageData: string;
imageSource: number;

constructor( private camera: Camera,
           private clientService: ClientService,
           private s3: S3_Service,
           private clientDocService: ClientDocService,
           private crop: Crop,
           ...
```

I'm doing exactly what the crop plugin docs say to do so I'm a bit unsure why it's throwing this error:

> ```
> Crops images
> import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop/ngx';
>
> constructor(private crop: Crop) { }
>
> ...
> ```

Any idea how I can change this to get the build working?

Comment: can you show the code of the actual line that is failing?

Comment: I did... it's the constructor within my service.  That's the line that fails.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it will work for dev build but not with prod flags? Could it be a config.xml issue with API targets?

Comment: I'm not too sure, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Indeed :) T'would be helpful post as complete info as possible. For example, the config.xml, package.json, Also, when I count the lines above, import is on line 16 which makes me think something else is on line 22, unless this code is reformatted from what is in your IDE..

Comment: Yeah, I did not include the addt'l imports at the top of the file as I do not think they are necessary.  I had no idea this was related to the config.xml which is why I didn't post it.  I'm still not sure why I would need to